# AJAX issue with value.length

Tags: javascript, ajax

Below is a very simple AJAX request that works just fine until I put a simple statement inside of it. It's failing because of line #4.

```
var wlen = str.value.length
```

Below is the AJAX code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function name_search(str)
{
var wlen = str.value.length;
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("name_div").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","/it/device/action/name_search_new.php?q="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
```

The **name_search_new.php** page looks up similar values to what is typed in the text box and returns those values. This page is irrelevant to this issue though because **any php page will always fail with the line 4 new variable/assignment and it will always work with the variable/assignment gone.**

If it helps, the request for this function is listed below... It also fails within a 'textarea' box too.

```
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="" style="color:red" 
placeholder="Device/Item(Required)" onkeyup="name_search(this.value)" />
```

Any help is appreciated,
Jay

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to do `str.value.length`.  `str.length` is what you need.

here is a jsfiddle demonstrating:

http://jsfiddle.net/ahEeH/

Comment: Hmmm, now that I see it, it makes perfect sense.  Thanks!  And thanks for the jsfiddle.net reference - very cool!

Comment: jsfiddle is a great tool for testing things out, i use it ALL the time :)

Answer (score 3):

You are calling `name_search(this.value)`; thus, `str = this.value`. Your line 4 then effectively executes `this.value.value.length`. However, `this.value` is a string, which doesn't have a property called `value` - so `this.value.value` is undefined. Accessing a property on undefined will fail.

Change to `str.length` and it should work.

BTW: the problem has nothing to do with AJAX.

Comment: Thanks, now that I see where the mistake is, it makes sense.  You're correct in that it has nothing to do with AJAX, but at the time, I couldn't figure out what the issue was so I wasn't able to rule out a possible AJAX issue.